# Fastest way to access cell value in bound DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, performance, datagridview

I have a DataGridView that is bound to a BindingList of objects and I need to access the value of a particular cell in each row as quickly as possible.  Is it faster to do:

```
if (((ObjectType)row.DataBoundItem).StringProperty != string.Empty)
{
}
```

...or...

```
if (row.Cells["STRINGPROPERTY"].Value != string.Empty)
{
}
```

Or is there another way that's faster than both of these?

Comment: Have you measured how long each takes?

Comment: @StuartDunkeld I'm working on it right now.  I was just curious if anyone could look at that and say, "Oh, the first way will definitely be slower because of the cast", etc.

Comment: Between those two, I'd say the one without the cast is always faster.

Comment: If you know the index of the cell, that may be quicker than accessing by name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot of way to check the value with if is *empty* or *null* but from your main question you can go and try to [Benchmarking method calls in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1622440/benchmarking-method-calls-in-c-sharp)

1. [String.IsNullOrEmpty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty.aspx)
2. [String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace.aspx)
3. [Best way to check if column returns a null value (from database to .net application)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2017533/best-way-to-check-if-column-returns-a-null-value-from-database-to-net-applicat)