# Getting the correct execution timings of a C# method using the StopWatch class

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress-gridcontrol

I have been using `stopwatch` in one of my `DevExpress` based application. I have created a `FlaUI` based test case that initiates the `keyboard`, enters a value and then moves to the next column. Now, there are like 20+ columns in a row in the DevExpress grid I am using. While I try to run that test case 5 times to come to a baseline timing, I am seeing too much different results.

I am pasting an extract of my current code here:

```
 public bool CreateNewGdistVoyageForPerformanceTesting(IEnumerable<GdistBenchVoyageParameters> gdistparameters,
        string gridAutomationId)
    {
        var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch
            .StartNew(); //This line of code is being used to monitor the time taken by each Keyboard operation

        long TotalTimeConsumed = 0;
        int MaxAllowedTime = 0;
        int HasTimeExceeded = 0;
        bool TimeHasNotExceeded = true;

        watch.Start();
        _logger.Info("Creating a new GDIST Voyage");
        TabItem ParentControl = VoyageEditorTabControl.SelectedTabItem;
        var CurrentSelectedTab = VoyageEditorTabControl.SelectedTabItemIndex;
        var ParentGrid = VoyageEditorTabControl.TabItems[CurrentSelectedTab]
            .FindFirstDescendant(cf => cf.ByAutomationId(gridAutomationId)).AsGrid();
        _controlAction.Highlight(ParentGrid);
        var Pattern = ParentGrid.Patterns.Grid;
        var RowCount = Pattern.Pattern.RowCount;
        var ColumnCount = Pattern.Pattern.ColumnCount;
        _logger.Info("======================================================================================");
        if (ParentGrid.AutomationId.Equals("ParentGridControl"))
        {
            _logger.Info($"Performance Testing on GDIST's View Main Grid :{gridAutomationId}");
            _logger.Info($"Current Grid Row count is: {RowCount}");

            _logger.Info("Creating a new voyage for GDIST Bench");
        }
        else
        {
            _logger.Info($"Performance Testing on GDIST's  Similar Voyages Panel Grid: {gridAutomationId}");
            _logger.Info($"Current Grid Row count is: {RowCount}");
            _logger.Info("Editing an existing voyage for GDIST Bench's Similar Voyages Panel");

        }

        for (int i = 0; i < ColumnCount; i++)
        {
            var cell = ParentGrid.Patterns.Grid.Pattern.GetItem(ParentGrid.RowCount - 1, i);

            if (cell == null)
            {
                _logger.Warning("No Columns found with matching Automation Ids");

                break;
            }

            if (cell.AutomationId.Equals("Vessel"))
            {
                MaxAllowedTime = 1500;
                gdistparameters.ToList().ForEach(voyageDetailsField =>
                {

                    if (voyageDetailsField.VesselId != null)
                    {
                        _logger.Info("Adding Data in Vessel ID  ");
                        cell.Focus();
                        cell.Click();
                        _logger.Info($"Entered value is:{voyageDetailsField.VesselId}");
                        watch.Stop(); // trying this to ensure the watch dummy run to remove JIT noise
                        if (!watch.IsRunning)
                        {
                            watch.Restart(); //starting the watch
                        }
                        Keyboard.Type(voyageDetailsField.VesselId.Trim());
                        watch.Stop();
                        Keyboard.Press(VirtualKeyShort.TAB);
                        //  _controlAction.WaitFor(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 2));
                        Wait.UntilInputIsProcessed();

                        _logger.Info($"Execution Time: {watch.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms");
                        if (watch.ElapsedMilliseconds > MaxAllowedTime)
                        {
                            HasTimeExceeded++;
                            _logger.Warning($"The data entry time has exceeded beyond the fixed value by {watch.ElapsedMilliseconds - MaxAllowedTime} ms");
                        }
                        TotalTimeConsumed = TotalTimeConsumed + watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
                    }
                });


                TotalTimeConsumed = TotalTimeConsumed + watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;

            }



            if (cell.AutomationId.Equals("LoadDate")) //Load Date
            {
                MaxAllowedTime = 500;
                gdistparameters.ToList().ForEach(voyageDetailsField =>
                {
                    //  _logger.Info("Adding data into the Load Date field");

                    if (voyageDetailsField.LoadDate != null)
                    {
                        _logger.Info("Adding Data in Load Date ");
                        cell.Focus();
                        cell.Click();
                        _logger.Info($"Entered value is:{voyageDetailsField.LoadDate}");
                        watch.Stop(); // trying this to ensure the watch dummy run to remove JIT noise
                        if (!watch.IsRunning)
                        {
                            watch.Restart(); //starting the watch
                        }

                        Keyboard.Type(voyageDetailsField.LoadDate.Trim());
                        watch.Stop();
                        Keyboard.Press(VirtualKeyShort.TAB);
                        //  _controlAction.WaitFor(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 2));
                        Wait.UntilInputIsProcessed();

                        _logger.Info($"Execution Time: {watch.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms");
                        if (watch.ElapsedMilliseconds > MaxAllowedTime)
                        {
                            HasTimeExceeded++;
                            _logger.Warning(
                                $"The data entry time has exceeded beyond the fixed value by {watch.ElapsedMilliseconds - MaxAllowedTime} ms");
                        }

                        TotalTimeConsumed = TotalTimeConsumed + watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
                    }
                });


                TotalTimeConsumed = TotalTimeConsumed + watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;



            }
```

The timings that I have been observing via the `logger` functionality is below.

[image]

I have run this on multiple PCs, multiple environments but the results are very different. The 5th run is actually taking a lot in every single case.

Note also that all the data that is being entered in populated when the application loads so network latency shouldn't be a problem here.

Moreover, I read that StopWatch comes with a lot of JIT noise, and yes, I had experienced it every time it was running for the first time, so I have already given it a false start in my code.

This test is a performance test and requires benchmarking. We can decide on the benchmarking with such big difference in the numbers.

Comment: I'd recommend: not using stopwatch but use an actual benchmarking tool (like BenchmarkDotNet). Or, have a read at these Q&A, they give tricks on how to use stopwatch. [Benchmarking method calls in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1622440/benchmarking-method-calls-in-c-sharp) - [Exact time measurement for performance testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/969290/exact-time-measurement-for-performance-testing)

Comment: [Benchmarking small code samples in C#, can this implementation be improved?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1047218/benchmarking-small-code-samples-in-c-can-this-implementation-be-improved)  -  [How to measure code performance in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/457605/how-to-measure-code-performance-in-net)

Comment: 3rd party GUI toolkits are always slow, DevExpress is no exception

Comment: @Pac0 I am automating a test and would like to use windows APIs due to the limitations